# Four Directions #2 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

To the North is a place you could wear on your feet
To the South is a place that could mean alone
To the West they play a ba' game in the street
To the East is where Hallvard sits on his throne

I've been a tall and proud trio for three decades and a half.
Where and what am I?

[Four Directions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/four-directions-where-and-what-am-i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial:
I think you are somewhere in :

> Norway or North sea

Explaination:

> **To the West they play a ba' game in the street** - BA game is a version of medieval football played in Scotland, primarily in Orkney and the Scottish Borders, around Christmas and New Year. 
> **To the East is where Hallvard sits on his throne** - Hallvard Kirke Norway
> **To the South is a place that could mean alone** - sola - Sola is a municipality in Rogaland county, Norway. it mean Alone in Spanish
>  Sandal is also a place in Norway, just to the north from Sola.

The part between these places is

> Norway or North sea

Damn I found it:

> **I've been a tall and proud trio for three decades and a half.**
> It's in Stavanger: [**Sverd i fjell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sverd_i_fjell) - The monument was created by sculptor Fritz Røed from Bryne and was unveiled by King Olav V of Norway in 1983. The three bronze swords stand 10 metres (33 ft) tall and are planted into the rock of a small hill next to the fjord.

Comment: You’ve correctly identified those three clues and your partial answer is also correct.  Getting close!

Comment: @MetaZen.. edited my answer

Comment: That's it!  Nice work.