# Four Directions #3 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

To the North, a mule may serve you in copper.
To the South, you may end up rich or a pauper.
To the West, "Keep it Weird" you may hear them mutter.
To the East, if you visit, bring plenty of butter.

I slithered for ages while the devils looked on.  Where and what am I?


[Four Directions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/four-directions-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72914/four-directions-2-where-and-what-am-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are

> [Snake River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_River)?

To the North, a mule may serve you in copper.

> The [Moscow mule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_mule) is a drink served in a copper mug, so this could point to [Moscow, Idaho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow%2C_Idaho).

To the South, you may end up rich or a pauper.

> To the south is Las Vegas with its gambling opportunities.

To the West, "Keep it Weird" you may hear them mutter.

> To the west is Oregon, which is where you might hear the phrase "[keep Portland weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_Portland_Weird)".

To the East, if you visit, bring plenty of butter.

> Not sure about this one. To the east are [Salmon River Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon_River_Mountains), and you use butter to cook salmon?

I slithered for ages while the devils looked on.

> Snake River slithers through [Hells Canyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hells_Canyon) on the border of Oregon and Idaho.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track.  Your answers for South and West are correct.    For East, a hint might be r13(abgr gur jbeq "oevat")

Comment: That's correct!  For East, I was referring to r13(ohggre sbe cbgngbrf (Vqnub))   That could just be what I like!  :)

Comment: Also, the last clue refers both to the answer and to r13(Frira Qrivyf Zbhagnvaf) which are just to the East.

Comment: @MetaZen Oh, I see. Lots of devils lurking about over there!