# Four Directions #4 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

To the North a dusty foot philosopher was born
To the South as you go, the colder the weather
To the West is a brown leaf - wait is that a horn?
To the East is a place to get back together

I'm with a group of fellow ghosts hanging out at the park.  Where and what am I?

[Four Directions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/four-directions-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72914/four-directions-2-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72983/four-directions-3-where-and-what-am-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standing on the shoulders of giants @deep thought, @El-Guest, and @GarethMcCaughan, the final answer is:

> I am a lemur and I'm quite literally at [Lemurs' Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemurs'_Park) on Madagascar

Comment: That is correct!  Thanks for wrapping this one up.

Answer (score 9):

To the East is a place to get back together

> réunion, an island east of madagascar

To the South as you go, the colder the weather

> nothing but sea to the south of madagascar, until you get to antarctica

To the North a dusty foot philosopher was born

> [deleted my wrong guess, @El-Guest got this one]: to the north is Somalia, where K'Naan is from.

To the West is a brown leaf - wait is that a horn?

> [deleted my wrong guess, @StoneGiant got this one]: It is the brown leaf chameleon on the east side of Madagascar.

I'm with a group of fellow ghosts hanging out at the park. Where and what am I?

> [deleted my wrong guess, @GarethMcCaughan got this one]: Madagascar is famous for lemurs. Their name comes from [a latin word for spirits of the dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemur#Etymology).

But more specifically,

> We're in a park... which one? Well, [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Brookesia_superciliaris_distribution.png) is where the brown leaf is found, and [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Mada_PAs.jpg) is a map of the national parks of Madagascar (in yellow). The brown leaf is basically on the east coast, but it's said to be to the west of our park, so... it looks like [Masoala National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoala_National_Park) on that bit sticking out on the northeast.

Comment: Nice answer! I think r13(gb gur Abegu vf Fbznyvn, fvapr "qhfgl sbbgrq cuvybfbcure" ersref gb X'anna).

Comment: East and South are correct.  @El-Guest is correct about North.  West is not what I had in mind and the final answer is not that, but it's a great guess.  You're getting very close!

Comment: The ghosts are a nice bit of etymology. @deepthought you will not go far wrong by considering what the place in question is famous for.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I never would have got that, I skipped latin class that day I guess.

Comment: Getting really close - I'll wait for a more specific "where" before marking it answered.  If you can come up with the West clue, that will just be a bonus :)

Comment: The brown leaf is probably a chameleon from the east side of Madagascar.  See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_leaf_chameleon) for details. Since the brown leaf is west, that would put us on the east coast.  Probably the city of Mohanoro or Mananjary?

Comment: @StoneGiant good catch! - though it might not be a city at all, since the OP mentions a park

Comment: Ah, I have to apologize, you are correct about the leaf, but I found reference to it in r13(Zbmnzovdhr), but you are correct about where it is mainly located.  So the "to the west" is referencing r13(Zbmnzovdhr), so the area the park can be in is a bit wider.  And will be pretty obvious when you see it.

Comment: r13(Enabznsnan Angvbany Cnex) then? I mean, r13(Zbmnzovdhr) is pretty big. You could draw a line from it to the eastern island through just about any of the national parks. But, I'm probably just being dumb.

Comment: That's how it looks to me too, east of r13(Zbmnzovdhr) could be just about any one of them. In that case I pick my original deleted answer! You are in r13(mbzovgfr angvbany cnex), you are a r13(mbzovr)... get it? r13(MBZOVgfr, zbMNZOVdhr)!! ;-) ;-)

Comment: Ha!  You're right, it does still create a pretty large area.  Last hint:  It's not a national park, but a small reserve for our friendly ghosts :)

Comment: @MetaZen Reminds me of the amusement park, Joyland, that is now abandoned. And is where our friendly ghosts reside, hahah :D

Comment: Haha - @deepthought has it so close.  The final answer will be very obvious when someone finds the park in question.  :)

Comment: @MetaZen Rather obviously, r13(Yrzhe'f cnex)?

Comment: If you write that up as an answer, I might have to check the box and give the bounty :)

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova  It's funny, I did see r13(Yrzhe'f cnex). But I was overthinking it.