# Four Directions #5 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> To the West, they are young and grand
>   To the North, they are high and briny
>   To the East, they are enchanting and jolly
>   To the South, they are rising and shiny
>   
>   I'm all at once and none at all.

### Where and what am I?

---

Hint #1:

> Each direction line is describing two separate things - one adjective for each.

Hint #2:

> Although hint #1 is true, there are only four things being described

Hint #3:

> Four of the adjectives should really be capitalized.

Hint #4:

> This rancher doesn't grow corn, but he sure does use a lot.

Hint #5:

> ...from the ashes

Hint #6:

> High?  Or like...high?  Yes.  And...yeah, could be!

[Four Directions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/four-directions-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72914/four-directions-2-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72983/four-directions-3-where-and-what-am-i)
[Four Directions #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/four-directions-4-where-and-what-am-i)

Comment: I'm addicted to these now.

Comment: Me too!  I have one more in the works and was happy to see someone else was inspired to create #6 :)

Comment: @MetaZen Does 'briny' have something to do with the Dead Sea?

Comment: No, but I like your thought process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of every clue, but I think you are

> the Four Corners states (Arizona, New Mexico, Colorado and Utah).

To the West, they are young and grand

> Brigham Young founded Salt Lake City in Utah, the Grand Canyon is in Arizona.

To the North, they are high and briny

> Colorado has tall mountains and legal marijuana, the Great Salt Lake is in Utah.

To the East, they are enchanting and jolly

> New Mexico is the "land of enchantment", Jolly Rancher candy is made in Colorado.

To the South, they are rising and shiny

> Phoenix rises from the ashes and is a city in Arizona. Not sure why New Mexico is shiny...

I'm all at once and none at all.

> "Four Corners" refers to all the states together. I think the actual corner area is a Native American territory not under the control of any of the states?

Comment: Yes, that's it!  For South, check out r13(gur synt) and the actual final answer I had in mind is what is found at the exact spot, which will make sense if you look it up. But this is the answer - full credit.

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> A member of the Baratheon family in the Crownlands? (Game of thrones)

To the West, they are young and grand

> The westerlands, home to the lannisters. A family that's definitly very grand (or so it thinks).

To the North, they are high and briny

> The iron islands, home to the Greyjoys. They worship the seagod and their leader must literally drown in salt water.

To the East, they are enchanting and jolly

> The Dothraki, home to the Dothraki horde. Always in large numbers raping and plundering as they go seemingly having a great time.

To the South, they are rising and shiny

> Dorne, home to the Dornish. A very flashy breed. Always wearing fancy looking armor and weapons and in the shiniest gowns.

Comment: That is not the place, but I really like this answer.  Though while the Dothraki may be jolly, I'm not sure they would be considered enchanting haha.